# Custom query with custom filtering returning incorrect results

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, tax-query

I've setup a custom query, I'm using Woocommerce and I am aware that it has it's own functionality, but have been tasked with creating custom filtering with a traditionally paged product/category archive pages

#### What have I done so far and what is happening?

###### Issue: The first page does not return the correct number of posts

This is my first real exposure with Woocom and custom filtering. I am getting some strange results and I have obviously made an error in my queries and filtering.

I have setup my query as normal using `WP_Query` along with associated `$args`

```php
// archive-product.php

// Set some basic defaults here
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_type = 'product';
$post_num = 16;
$orderby = array(
  '_stock_status' => 'ASC',
  '_price' => 'DESC',
);

$tax_query = $meta_query = null;

 $args = array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_num,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    // Order by stock status first, then by price
    'orderby' => $orderby
  );

$products = new WP_Query($args);
```

This snippet here will give some context to the first issue I am encountering. On page 1, the query returns 15, not 16 items. The following pages appear to display the correct number, but the first page misses one off.

I did add the following to my functions file (and removed `posts_per_page` from `$args`) but it do not seem to resolve it.

```php
// functions.php

function custom_posts_per_page( $query ) {
  if ( !$query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    if( $query->get('post_type') == 'product' ) {
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 16 );
    }
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page' );
```

In the admin area, under Reading, the number of posts is also set to 16.

###### Issue: When filtered, pagination still shows as if all products are being queried, but the last few pages are completely empty

As I mentioned, this is my first real exposure to custom queries in WP. No doubt there is an issue in how I have set this up, but I will attempt to explain what I am doing

```php
$meta_query = array(
  'relation' => 'AND', array(
    '_stock_status' => array(
      'key' => '_stock_status',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    '_price' => array(
      'key' => '_price',
      'compare' => 'EXISTS',
      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    ),
  ),
);
```

The`$meta_query` is being setup in this way as the products need to first sort by `_stock_status` then by `_price`.

If someone selects a product price, its value is added to the `$meta_query`

```php
// If a selection to product price has been made, add this to the meta query
if( isset($_GET['product-price']) && $_GET['product-price'] != '' ) {
  $arr = explode(':', $_GET['product-price']);

  $meta_query[] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND', array(
      'key' => '_price',
      'value' => $arr,
      'type' => 'numeric',
      'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
    ),
  );
};
```

And similar is happening for `product-type` and `product-brand`, except they modify the `$tax_query`

```php
// If a selection to product type has been made, add this to the tax query
if( isset($_GET['product-type']) && $_GET['product-type'] != '' ) {
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND', array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $_GET['product-type']
    )
  );
};

// If a selection to product brand has been made, add this to the tax query
if(  isset($_GET['product-brand']) && $_GET['product-brand'] != '' ) {
  $tax_query[] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND', array(
      'taxonomy' => 'pa_brands',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array($_GET['product-brand'])
    )
  );
};
```

I appear to be getting the correct filtering, so based on the arguments passed to `$_GET` the query is being modified accordingly. Apart from the pagination - which is a custom implementation (could this be the cause?):

```php
function wordpress_numeric_post_nav() {
    if( is_singular() )
        return;
    global $wp_query;
    /* Stop the code if there is only a single page page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
    /*Add current page into the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;
    /*Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }
    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }

    $arrow = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 51 37.875">
                    <path d="M52.373,30.011,36.643,14.731a3.871,3.871,0,0,0-5.315,0,3.609,3.609,0,0,0,0,5.163l9.287,9.074H6.258a3.652,3.652,0,1,0,0,7.3H40.616l-9.287,9.022a3.609,3.609,0,0,0,0,5.163,3.837,3.837,0,0,0,5.368,0L52.373,35.227A3.661,3.661,0,0,0,53.5,32.619,3.457,3.457,0,0,0,52.373,30.011Z" transform="translate(53.5 51.55) rotate(180)"/>
                </svg>';

    echo '<div class="e-pagination pagination-navigation">
            <div class="e-pagination__inner">
                <div class="e-pagination__container">
                    <ul class="e-pagination__list">' . "\n";
    /*Display Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li class="e-pagination__prev">%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link($arrow) );
    /*Display Link to first page*/
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>';
    }
    /* Link to current page */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }
    /* Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }
    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li class="e-pagination__next">%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link($arrow) );
        echo '</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>' . "\n";
}
```

That seems to be a complete outline of the issue I am having, any help would be appreciated

```
// complete archive-product.php


  <form class="filter" method="GET">
      <div class="container">
          Filters: 
          <?php 
          
          /**
           * Product Type Selection
          */
          $product_types = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => $product_cat_term_id,
          ]);
          
          ?>
          <select class="select" name="product-type" id="product-type" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="">Product Type</option>
            <?php foreach($product_types as $product_type) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $product_type->slug ?>" <?= (isset($_GET['product-type'])) ? selected($_GET['product-type'], $product_type->slug) : null ?>><?= $product_type->name ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>

          <?php 
          /**
           * Product Brand Selection
          */
          $product_brands = get_terms( [
            'taxonomy'    => 'pa_brands', 
            'hide_empty'  => true,
            'parent'      => 0
          ]); 

          ?>
          <select class="select" name="product-brand" id="product-brand" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="">Brand</option>
            <?php foreach($product_brands as $product_brand) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $product_brand->slug ?>" <?= (isset($_GET['product-brand'])) ? selected($_GET['product-brand'], $product_brand->slug) : null ?>><?= $product_brand->name ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>

          <?php 
          /**
           * Product Price Selection
          */
          ?>
          <select class="select" name="product-price" id="product-price" onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="">Price</option>
            <option value="0:99" <?= (isset($_GET['product-price'])) ? selected($_GET['product-price'], '0:99') : null ?>>Under £100</option>
            <option value="100:250" <?= (isset($_GET['product-price'])) ? selected($_GET['product-price'], '100:250') : null ?>>£100 - £250</option>
            <option value="251:10000" <?= (isset($_GET['product-price'])) ? selected($_GET['product-price'], '251:10000') : null ?>>Over £250</option>
          </select>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div class="list">
    <div class="b-product-list__items">
        <?php

        if($products->have_posts()) :
          while($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
          endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;

        ?>
        <?php echo wordpress_numeric_post_nav(); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query syntax looked good, although you could instead add a direct meta/taxonomy query *clause* array such as `$meta_query[] = array( 'key' => '_price', ... )` instead of `$meta_query[] = array( 'relation' => 'AND', array( 'key' => '_price', ... ) )`.

However, I spotted 2 main issues with your code:

**Issue 1: Your custom pagination function will not work correctly with secondary `WP_Query` queries.**

Because the function (`wordpress_numeric_post_nav`) was intended only for the main WordPress query which is referenced using the global `$wp_query` object.

So if you want that function to work with [secondary or custom `WP_Query` queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops), then you need to adjust your function so that it supports custom `WP_Query` instances like your `$products` object.

Here's a simple modification you can try:

1. Change the `function wordpress_numeric_post_nav()` to:

   ```php
   function wordpress_numeric_post_nav( $wp_query = null )
   ```
2. Then in that function, change the `global $wp_query;` to:

   ```php
   if ( ! is_a( $wp_query, 'WP_Query' ) ) {
       global $wp_query;
   }
   ```

So with that, you'll display the pagination like so:

```php
echo wordpress_numeric_post_nav( $products );
```

**Issue 2: You should use the `pre_get_posts` action and *not* creating a secondary `WP_Query` query and loop.**

The main query also uses `paged` as the pagination query var (which is read from the URL of, or matching rewrite rule for the current page), hence it will conflict with the pagination for secondary `WP_Query` queries *on archive pages like your `product` post type archive*, because the main query could have less number of pages than secondary queries, leading to 404 errors.

So although 404 error isn't or may not be the problem here, I strongly suggest you to use the `pre_get_posts` action to apply your custom meta and taxonomy filters.

So just remove that `$products = new WP_Query($args);` (and the variables, etc. used for that piece of code) from your template ([`archive-product.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types)) and then:

1. In the theme functions file, add this snippet:

   ```php
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_product_archive_pre_get_posts' );
   function my_product_archive_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
       // Checks whether we are on the product archive page and that the current
       // WP_Query instance is the main query. We also don't want to affect admin
       // posts queries, hence we do `! is_admin()` check.
       if ( ! is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) &&
           $query->is_main_query()
       ) {
           $tax_query  = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
           $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );

           // Sorts the posts by the stock status and then price.
           $meta_query[] = array(
               'relation'      => 'AND',
               '_stock_status' => array(
                   'key'     => '_stock_status',
                   'compare' => 'EXISTS',
               ),
               '_price'        => array(
                   'key'     => '_price',
                   'compare' => 'EXISTS',
               ),
           );

           // Filter by a specific price range.
           if ( ! empty( $_GET['product-price'] ) ) {
               $range  = sanitize_text_field( $_GET['product-price'] );
               $prices = array_map( 'intval', explode( ':', $range ) );

               $meta_query[] = array(
                   'key'     => '_price',
                   'value'   => $prices,
                   'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                   'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
               );
           }

           // Filter by a specific product type.
           if ( ! empty( $_GET['product-type'] ) ) {
               $tax_query[] = array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                   'field'    => 'slug',
                   'terms'    => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['product-type'] ),
               );
           }

           // Filter by a specific product brand.
           if ( ! empty( $_GET['product-brand'] ) ) {
               $tax_query[] = array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'pa_brands',
                   'field'    => 'slug',
                   'terms'    => sanitize_text_field( $_GET['product-brand'] ),
               );
           }

           // Now modify the main query's arguments.
           $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 16 );
           $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
           $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
           $query->set(
               'orderby',
               array(
                   '_stock_status' => 'ASC',
                   '_price'        => 'DESC',
               )
           );
       }
   }
   ```

   **Hint:** You can actually just use the `'<taxonomy>' => '<term slug>'` format, hence you can remove the `$tax_query` parts and do something like:

   ```php
   // Filter by a specific product type.
   if ( ! empty( $_GET['product-type'] ) ) {
       $query->set( 'product_cat', sanitize_text_field( $_GET['product-type'] ) );
   }

   // Filter by a specific product brand.
   if ( ! empty( $_GET['product-brand'] ) ) {
       $query->set( 'pa_brands', sanitize_text_field( $_GET['product-brand'] ) );
   }
   ```
2. In your template, replace the `$products->have_posts()` with `have_posts()` and then the `$products->the_post()` with `the_post()`, i.e. just use the [main loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#basic-examples) to display the posts.

*That way, you would not need to modify your pagination function and simply use `echo wordpress_numeric_post_nav();` to display the pagination.*

#### Additional Notes

1. On singular pages like a Page (post type `page`), your secondary `WP_Query` query and loop, as well as the pagination, would work properly. (Because the main query does *not* use `paged`)
2. WordPress core has built-in pagination functions like [`the_posts_pagination()` and `paginate_links()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/#numerical-pagination).
3. You can learn more about the main (WordPress) query at https://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview.

   <sub>Sorry, I could not find an updated version of the above article on the [WordPress Developer Resources site](https://developer.wordpress.org/)..</sub>

Comment: That was very useful, and great in-depth explanations of where I was going wrong. For the past few years my go-to for custom queries has been WP_Query, in all situations, other than the main loop so its a bit of an eye-opener to see that it may have been potentially causing issues in other builds. However, its reassuring to see that I have the basics of tax and meta queries understood.